# Обособление пояснительного члена предложения

Tags: пунктуация, тире

Как правильно:

*Родился и вырос он в прекрасном городе — Москве*
 или
*Родился и вырос он в прекрасном городе, Москве*?

И еще вопрос: чем приложение отличается от пояснения?

Comment: А что, родиться можно НЕ в родном городе? Да и вырасти тоже... Не проще сказать: родился и вырос в Москве? Скромненько и со вкусом, и все вопросы отпали.

Comment: Изменил предложение, чтобы оно никого не раздражало.

Comment: Не нужны тут ни тире, ни запятая.

Comment: @Niemand Почему?

Comment: Нет причин для постановки. Ну, если уж очень хотите, чтобы при чтении "Москву" выделяли – ставьте тире.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Родился и вырос он в прекрасном городе — Москве.**

> При отсутствии пояснительных союзов то есть, именно, а именно и при наличии пояснения выделение происходит обычно с помощью тире, а не запятой. 
>   Разговор шёл один – о погоде; Профессия его была самая мирная – учитель.
>   ([Пояснительные члены предложения](https://licey.net/free/4-russkii_yazyk/40-kurs_russkogo_yazyka_sintaksis_i_punktuaciya/stages/724-28_utochnyayuschie__poyasnitelnye_i_prisoedinitelnye_chleny_predlozheniya.html))

Приложение — это разновидность определения, а в качестве пояснения (пояснительной конструкции) могут выступать и определения, и другие члены  члены предложения. Пояснения (а также члены предложения со значением уточнения и  присоединения) имеют функцию добавочных сообщений.

"Родился и вырос он в прекрасном городе Москве" — здесь приложение. 
"Родился и вырос он в прекрасном городе — Москве" — здесь пояснение.

Answer (score 1):

1) Возможны два варианта:

**Родился и вырос он в прекрасном городе — Москве**. Уточняюще-пояснительное значение, наличие паузы.

**Родился и вырос он в прекрасном городе Москве.** Определительное значение.

Если автор решил обособить приложение, то  здесь нужно использовать **тире,** но выбор знака (запятая или тире) зависит **от структуры предложения.**

2) **Приложение, как и определение, может иметь значение пояснения/уточнения.**

**Приехала сестра Маша**. Определение.

**Приехала Маша, сестра. Приехала сестра, Маша.** Уточнение. Здесь приложение и определяемое слово меняются местами

3) **Примеры** (обособление одиночных приложений с разными значениями **запятой**):

А враги, **дурни**, думают, что мы смерти боимся.

У нас был **один** ротмистр, **остряк, забавник** (пояснение).

К брату зашёл наш сосед, **студент**.

Обе старшие девочки, **Катя и Соня**, стали зорко следить за мальчиками.

Тут были и капитан, и поручик, и Онисим Михайлович, **фельдфебель**.

Сергей Никанорыч, **буфетчик**, налил пять стаканов чаю.

Жёлтая бабочка, **лимонница**, сидит на бруснике.